# Preview Crashing and issues with calling a view in swiftui

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

Essentially, I am developing an app right now, and I wanted to put the first view onto the ContentView page, but I was met with an error.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DImDZ.png)

I have this temporary navigation set up so that the code can compile for me to demonstrate the issue. I am thrown a can not find OpenLoopsView in scope error when I try to call it normally (OpenLoopsView is the name of my view)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQkvf.png)

when the button is clicked to take me to my view I am taken to this page.

[First Part of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD3Ac.png)
[Code Continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4JjJ.png)
This is the OpenLoopsView if it helps at all

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

I had tried looking on stack overflow and deleting some files that were in the package contents of the .xcodeproj file, but the problems persisted and those files somehow spawned back in.

Comment: See [ask] including the section about including code as text and not images

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the right solution or not. However, most of the time that happens, it's usually that the contentView.swift file's target is not as same as the OpenLoopsView.swift file's target.

Expand the right sidebar and check Target Membership for both files are the same. Otherwise the views inside those files will not be accessible to each other.

Comment: Just checked and the target membership for both files is the same. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Have you checked the Diagnostics? There is an diagnostics icon on top of canvas simulator. Press it and see what's wrong. Sometimes it provides important information about crashes.

Comment: Im sorry where exactly is the diagnostics icon? I checked around the canvas simulator and can't see. If you have a picture that would help

Comment: It's beside the reload button on canvas simulator.  [see this](https://ibb.co/283bqDH)
Also, check if all the subviews used in OpenLoopsView has the same target.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).